# Rails asset caching -- cannot get max-age to set

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, heroku, asset-pipeline

I'm having trouble getting rails to set the max-age value for any of my CSS or JS assets. We're running rails 3.1, but we upgraded so I am quite possibly missing some obvious piece of configurations. At this point, I've flipped most of the configs I can find from true to false and back again with no luck.

Here is my current environment/production.rb

```
Ventura::Application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb

  # Code is not reloaded between requests
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Configure static asset server for tests with Cache-Control for performance
  config.serve_static_assets = false
  config.static_cache_control = "public, max-age=3600"

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS
  config.assets.compress = true

  # Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
  config.assets.compile = true

  # Generate digests for assets URLs
  config.assets.digest = true

  # Defaults to Rails.root.join("public/assets")
  # config.assets.manifest = YOUR_PATH

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = "X-Sendfile" # for apache
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for nginx

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  # config.force_ssl = true

  # See everything in the log (default is :info)
  # config.log_level = :debug

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups
  # config.logger = SyslogLogger.new

  # Use a different cache store in production
  # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server
  # config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://assets.example.com"

  # Precompile additional assets (application.js, application.css, and all non-JS/CSS are already added)
  # config.assets.precompile += %w( search.js )

  # Disable delivery errors, bad email addresses will be ignored
  # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Default mailer URL
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'http://ventura-production.herokuapp.com/'}

  # Enable threaded mode
  # config.threadsafe!

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation can not be found)
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify
end
```

And this is in my application.rb

```
# Enable the asset pipeline
config.assets.enabled = true

# Version of your assets, change this if you want to expire all your assets
config.assets.version = '1.0'

# Don't load resources when precompiling
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
```

I am including the assets correctly, I think. Here's an example: `<%= javascript_include_tag "client/jquery", "client/jquery-ui-1_8_18", "client/bootstrap_min", "client/jquery-select-menu", "client/jquery_tablesorter", "client/jquery_tablesorter_pager", "client/application" %>`

And a partial trace on a request of any given page:

```
cache: [GET /assets/client/jquery-ui-1_8_18-d903da4c219079ca31f0ea1b23f89afc.css] fresh
cache: [GET /assets/client/bootstrap-2186f501bbd967564f2793c1c30aebc8.css] fresh
cache: [GET /assets/client/rg-5f04e577cfffd5dbcb8a1735ad211bd9.css] fresh
cache: [GET /assets/client/custom_charts-63eaad73c206c7ce6616c7f718be783f.css] fresh
cache: [GET /assets/client/bootstrap_min-afbee53fdd364c866cbd15abd6473012.js] fresh
cache: [GET /assets/client/jquery-select-menu-f2a3776430c5b4ead15173d0247f3f11.js] fresh
cache: [GET /assets/client/jquery_tablesorter-7fc613e34c891c852e2932f59bf91368.js] fresh
cache: [GET /assets/client/jquery_tablesorter_pager-141a886e7f35eb9f662b865516b23eca.js] fresh
cache: [GET /assets/client/jquery-689ca6a49fcbd1c3777b13d1abcc1316.js] fresh
cache: [GET /assets/client/application-6a61f272dd6a1ff7b5587435e67cd1bf.js] fresh
```

I should be able to avoid all these gets on every page-load. (and yes, I should not host most jquery stuff locally, on my to-do list)

Comment: Should that even be on a to-do list? It's replacing a line or two of code.

Comment: If you're serving assets with hash digests in the URL, have you considered just doing the caching at the Apache/Nginx level? That way you could set far-future cache expiration. Or are you just concerned with caching in development?

Comment: @StuartM We're running on heroku, and seeing the same behavior in prod as I am here in development. My theory is if I fix it for one, I fix it for both.

Comment: @StuartM Also, I don't really care about the digests. From the docs, seems like it was deemed a "good thing". My understanding is that with the digest, you can set the assets to expire infinitely in the future cause if they every change, you load a different digest. Problem is, they're not caching.

Comment: Have you tried `config.serve_static_assets = true`? See my answer below

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [Rails Configuration Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#rails-general-configuration) (emphasis mine):

> `config.serve_static_assets` configures Rails itself to serve static assets. Defaults to true, but in the production environment is turned off as the server software (e.g. Nginx or Apache) used to run the application should serve static assets instead. Unlike the default setting set this to true when running (absolutely not recommended!) or testing your app in production mode using WEBrick. **Otherwise you won´t be able use page caching and requests for files that exist regularly under the public directory will anyway hit your Rails app.**

I would try setting `config.serve_static_assets = true` if you haven't already.

**Update**: The [Heroku Dev Center](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rack-cache-memcached-rails31#serve-static-assets) also recommends this:

> To allow your application to properly serve, invalidate and refresh static assets several config settings must be updated in config/environments/production.rb. Allow Rails to serve assets with the `serve_static_assets` setting.

Comment: So, I set `serve_static_assets=true`. Still seeing no-cache responses.

Comment: Are you seeing the same when testing a cURL command? E.g., `curl -I http://your-host/path/to/asset`, what headers are in the response?

Comment: I stand corrected. While trying to narrow this down, this solution _is_ working. The max-age value the chrome and firefox are storing, though, continues to be 0. Is there no way to get browsers to not check if every asset is fresh on every load? So I see the response coming back from the server with max-age=3600, but chrome and firefox do the get on every page load.

Comment: Are you hitting "Refresh" in your browser or just navigating around different pages on your site normally? In the past I've seen that explicitly hitting "Refresh" can cause assets that were otherwise cached to reload. And re: forcing browsers to obey certain constraints, have you tried any other Cache-Control header instructions? See http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/#CACHE-CONTROL

Comment: Well, glad it's something obvious. My tests were flawed. I saw the problem originally when navigating, but have been testing various solutions by hitting refresh.

Comment: Cool. I've found `curl` to be one of the simplest ways to test cached responses since it takes the browser out of the equation entirely. Of course you eventually should test in the browser, but to isolate your cache testing curl helps a lot in my experience.